# How to export a formatted MS-Access report into HTML using a template file?

Tags: html, ms-access, bootstrap-4

I cannot format properly my exported MS Access report using a template html file.

I just found this tags and tokens for MS Access html templates:

```
<!--AccessTemplate_Body-->
<!--AccessTemplate_FirstPage-->        
<!--AccessTemplate_PreviousPage-->        
<!--AccessTemplate_NextPage-->        
<!--AccessTemplate_LastPage-->
<!--AccessTemplate_PageNumber-->
```

This is the code I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/...">
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <table class="table table-dark">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td scope="row"><!--AccessTemplate_Body--></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
     ...
</body>
</html>
```

The whole table is inserted in a cell. I could not find a proper tag / token for each table element: head, cell, ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much of MS Acces, but here's what I can offer. 
Tables usually looks like...

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Table Header A</th>
    <th>Table Header B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table Data A.1</td>
    <td>Table Data B.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Table Data A.2</td>
    <td>Table Data B.2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`<th>` for table headers (the column names) and `<td>` for table data, `<tr>` for each new row. You could try

It looks like, though, that you may be able to just do

```
<table>
<!--AccessTemplate_Body -->
</table>
```

I don't know exactly how it's taking an HTML comment and making it a table, but if it's already doing that, just do it inside the table instead of a table cell.

Additionally, usually when I import data into HTML, I use PHP to read either grab data from a database or read a text file -- if you have any experience with such things as File I/O, it'd be worth a shot.

Comment: I don't know about PHP. I will read more about it. The html file is used as template by MS Access, that replaces the comment by the report information.